# Google Maps API - If one address is not found, try another

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a google map API working great, but sometimes it doesn't throw up a result and I just get the dreaded grey box (depending on what address is being entered).

Here is my code:

```
  var map;
  var geocoder;
  var markers = new Array();
  var firstLoc;

  function myGeocodeFirst() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();



    geocoder.geocode( {'address': "<?php echo stripslashes($centre_name) . ", " . preg_replace('#\s+#',',',trim($address)); ?>" },
      function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          firstLoc = results[0].geometry.location;

          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
          {
            center: firstLoc,
            zoom: 16,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
          });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: firstLoc,
          animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
          map: map,
          title: '<?php echo stripslashes($centre_name); ?>'
        });

        var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
          '<span id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading"><?php echo stripslashes($centre_name); ?></span>'+
          '</div>';

          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map,marker);
          });

          var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
              content: contentString
          });

        }
      }
    );
  }
```

I would like it to try a second address if the first one provides no geolocation. Is this possible? I cannot find anything on the web at all.

I've tried various if/elses but it just seems to crash the code

Comment: How are you planning on providing the second address?  The basic concept would be to call the geocoder again in the callback with the second address if the status returned is no "OK".

Answer (score 0):

wouldn't you just check for a return status of something other than "OK".

check out the api page here

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#StatusCodes

Answer (score 0):

This will geocode "New York, NY" if the initial address fails with ZERO_RESULTS.

```
  var addresses = ["<?php echo stripslashes($centre_name) . ", " . preg_replace('#\s+#',',',trim($address)); ?>", "New York, NY"]

function myGeocodeFirst() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  geocoder.geocode( {'address': addresses[0] }, geocoderCallback);
}
function geocoderCallback(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    firstLoc = results[0].geometry.location;
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
    {
      center: firstLoc,
      zoom: 16,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: firstLoc,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        map: map,
        title: '<?php echo stripslashes($centre_name); ?>'
    });

    var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
          '<span id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading"><?php echo stripslashes($centre_name); ?></span>'+
          '</div>';

     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
          infowindow.open(map,marker);
     });

     var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
              content: contentString
     });

  } else if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
    geocoder.geocode( {'address': addresses[1] }, geocoderCallback);
  } else alert("Geocode failed, status:"+status);
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MzdJ3/)

Comment: Thanks for your help! Although, when I replace my code with yours I get the dreaded gray box again :(

Comment: I've slighty modified the code... I am doing if 

(status !== google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {

and my map is gray - presuming because the address I put in is "aewawerargaweg" and is not found. It still performs the map rendering and doesn't hit my 

alert('NOT FOUND');

Really struggling here :(

Comment: This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MzdJ3/) works for me.  Check your code for javascript errors.